Override relation field currently selected value display text
While using relation field, that allows to select one to many other nodes, I encountered in issue of not being able to change it's display. In my case, relations are people and their name is node title, and surname is stored in another field. I want to administrator to be able to see both name and surname instead of default selected value format "label (id)".

I found a way to use "reference method: views" and "view used to select entities", to change how autocomplete results look and they work as expected (1.), but I haven't found a way how to change currently selected value display (2.).
Have tried multiple hooks and preprocess field, form alter, display build alter and prerender with trusted callback, but it seems that I can't really impact displayed value, without resorting to complicated JavaScript solution, that I'm trying to avoid. Please direct me in the direction of solutions that should be attacked more deeply, as I struggle to understand how really EntityReferenceAutocompeleteWidget really works.

You can achieve this via using the hook_preprocess_field() or hook_field_formatter_view() hook to alter the output.
/**
 * Implements hook_field_formatter_view().
 */
function mymodule_field_formatter_view(array &$element, $entity_type, $entity, $field, $instance, $langcode, $items) {
  // Target the specific entity reference field.
  if ($field['field_name'] == 'field_people_reference') {
    foreach ($items as &$item) {
      // Load the referenced node.
      $referenced_node = \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::load($item['target_id']);
      if ($referenced_node) {
        // Get the title (name) and surname fields.
        $name = $referenced_node->getTitle();
        $surname = $referenced_node->get('field_surname')->value;

        // Modify the display format.
        $item['#markup'] = $name . ' ' . $surname;
      }
    }
  }
}


This looks logical, but I can't find info about this hook inside Drupal 10.x, it is present in 7.x, but not in 10.x

Since Drupal 8.x, Drupal uses formatter classes https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/converting-drupal-7-modules-to-drupal-8/d7-to-d8-upgrade-fields-widgets-and-formatters but I haven't found way to create override of existing field formatter, like in your example
